# Sharepoint 2013 workflow history change user ID

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

I'm creating a custom workflow in Sharepoint 2013 with Visual Studio for the approval of the elements added to a list. It's as simple as: A user creates the element (initiator) and a different one approves it (approver).

The problem comes when I use the **WriteToHistory** box to leave trace of the steps. The User ID in the history item that is created is always the initiator and there's no evident way of changing it. Therefore, I thought I could replace the **WriteToHistory** element with a **CreateListItem** to create the history item and all its fields manually. When I do so, I can update all of the fields in the history item (even the **WorkflowInstance** value, that links this new history item with its workflow instance) but not the User ID...

I'm getting the error when the workflows runs and tries to add the new history item

```
Retrying last request. Next attempt scheduled in less than one minute.
Details of last request: HTTP BadRequest to <siteURL>/_vti_bin/client.svc/web/lists(guid'<workflowHistoryListGUID>')/Items 
Correlation Id: 42e20e0f-61d2-4a35-9339-429d395dbdfb Instance Id: c329fba8-dbbd-4123-8411-b90a34ec8fbb
```

I don't know which items the last two GUIDs refer to. Additional information:

- I'm setting the User ID field using its internal name. This field type is a person or group but I don't know how to create an SPUser in the workflow. I've passed a GUID and an Int32 with the user id and nothing changed
- I'm not providing values for all the mandatory fields
- The rest of the fields work perfectly whatever their types are: string, dates, etc.

Can anybody advise the way of customizing the User ID in the history items? Thanks